# actionscript removing movieclip children

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, actionscript

Ive got a document class in this class I dynamically create movie clips, store them in an array and finally add it to the stage using addChild. That's all fine, the issue is though im trying to remove the movieClips through the array and it is throwing an error:

## 1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert []@26be1fb1 to flash.display.DisplayObject.

Here is my code:

```
    // Note i have declared the array outside the function, so that's not an issue
    function x (e:MouseEvent){
    
        
        if (thumbnails.length !== 0){ // Determine if any movieclips have already been created on stage and delete them
            for(var ctr:int = 0; ctr < thumbnails.length;ctr++ ){
                removeChild(thumbnails[ctr]);
                
            }
            
        }
        for (var i: int = 0;i < userIput; i++){ // Loop through and create instances of symbol
            
            
            var thumb:Thumbnail = new Thumbnail();
            
            thumb.y = 180; // Set y position
            thumb.x = 30 + ((thumb.width + 10) * i); 
            
            
            addChild(thumb);

            thumbnails[i] = [thumb]; // Add to array
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you paste the first line of `Thumbnail`? The one starting by `public class Thumbnail`...

Answer (score 1):

When you retrieve the `MovieClip` from your `Array`, you need to cast it as a `DisplayObject` before attempting to remove it:

```
    if (thumbnails.length !== 0){ // Determine if any movieclips have already been created on stage and delete them
        for(var ctr:int = 0; ctr < thumbnails.length;ctr++ ){
            removeChild(DisplayObject(thumbnails[ctr]));

        }

    }
```

Alternatively, you could consider using a `Vector` (a type-safe version of an `Array`) with the base-type set as `DisplayObject`:

```
var thumbnails:Vector.<DisplayObject> = new Vector.<DisplayObject>();
thumbnails.push(new MovieClip());

this.addChild(thumbnails[0]);
this.removeChild(thumbnails[0]);
```

For further reading, have a look at the Adobe documentation on [type conversion](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f87.html) and [`Vectors`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html).

**Update:**

Instead of adding an instance of `Thumbnail` to your `Array` the following line is actually adding a further `Array` containing a single element to your thumbnails `Array` (in effect you are creating a multi-dimensional `Array`):

```
// You're assigning an array literal with a single element 
// to this element of the the thumbnails array
thumbnails[i] = [thumb];
```

Try either of the following instead:

```
 // What you meant
 thumbnails[i] = thumb; 

 // Better
 thumbnails.push(thumb);
```

Comment: Tried it...but still throwing same error, I cast it to a display object and still not working, to debug I traced the actual array elements  and it printed [object Thumbnail] x many times depending on the userInput which I assume means the content in the array is not at fault

Comment: Thanks a lot that was the actual problem...should be without brackets thumb

Comment: No bother. Remember to accept the answer if it helped you out.

Answer (score 1):

The error that appears tells you that Flash Player cannot convert `[]@26be1fb1` to DisplayObject. The `[]@26be1fb1` gives you a hint what type of object at which address cannot be converted. `[]` is the type of object here that means the type `Array` so when `removeChild()` is called you try to pass an array to it, but the method expects DisplayObject.

#### Why this happens

Your code has a very simple but maybe unobstrusive problem, namely at this code line:

```
thumbnails[i] = [thumb]; // Add to array
```

You put your thumb into an array by using `[]` around `thumb`. So what your code actually is doing is that it adds an array with a single element (`thumb`) to the array `thumbnails`. After that you have an array of arrays with single elements.

#### Solution

Change the above line to:

```
thumbnails[i] = thumb; // Add to array
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: Saw to late that net.uk.sweet already answered it correctly. So you may ignore may answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

For your perceived issue:

Use Vector instead of Array
*or* cast array item to Thumbnail class

But the main culprit will probably be the fact **you never clear the items from the array**, you remove them from the parent/stage, but you do not remove them from the array… together with adding the items at a specific place in the array **will cause erratic behavior**:

you add them:
t[0] = item0_0
t[1] = item0_1
t[2] = item0_2
t[3] = item0_3

then remove item0_0, item0_1, item0_2, item0_3 from stage, but leave them in the array
next you add e.g. 2 new ones

t[0] = item1_0
t[1] = item1_1

so you have:
on stage:
 
item1_0
item1_1

in array:
t[0] = item1_0
t[1] = item1_1
t[2] = item0_2
t[3] = item0_3

This should be working:

```
var thumbnails:Vector.<Thumbnail> = new Vector.<Thumbnail>();

function x (e:MouseEvent) {

    var thumb:Thumbnail;

    for each(thumb in thumbnails){
        removeChild(thumb);
    }

    thumbnails = new Vector.<Thumbnail>(); // clear Vector by re-initiating it

    for (var i: int = 0;i < userIput; i++){ 
        thumb = new Thumbnail();

        // ...

        addChild(thumb);

        thumbnails.push(thumb);
    }
}
```